# Focus change by tabstop kills transformation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a little problem and somehow i can't find any solution. I have a div inside another div, and im moving this div with css3 translation. Inside this div, i have a variable amout of controls, like inputs.

Like this:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='content'>
        <input id='input1' type='text'/>
        <input id='input2' type='text'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

If the user cycles through those controls, the tabstop ruins the translation completly. And there is no hint WHERE the div now is. Here a little demo:

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfxLR/6/)

If you click on the first input and tab, your destination is the second input (bottom right, not visible at this time). The browser wants to put it in view, and kills the translation. All values stay the same, but the view is out of sync. Tab back with shift-tab will make it clear, the view is broken. The translation is still at -100, -100 all the time.

I want to prevent the browser from autoviewing the input. It may focus the box, but it must not scroll the view to the box. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello. Maybe I have missed something, but could you please explain a little more `"but it must not scroll the view to the box"`.

Comment: Maybe the better question is - what do you want to accomplish? So we could know what is the best solution for that

Comment: Well i am using something like that for a control, a container control. For example a popup with huge forms. Especially touch systems, mobile. Easy scrolling. The goal here is just that the browser does not reset the view when tabbing. If it does, the scrolling is destroyed, like in the example.

Tested with Firefox and Chrome, if you press tab inside input1, the browser centers the view on input2. BUT the dom does not know this, the transform is ignored. I want to disable this browser "center-view-on-node" behavior.